# Grails - criteria query for assoociation

Tags: grails

I have domain model like

```
class Event{

 ...

static belongsTo = [user:User]

}
```

and

```
class User{
  ...
  static hasMany = [events :Event];

}
```

Now I am simply want to search all events by specified user id. How can I do this? I'm not able to find any example.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the back-reference which is created by "belongsTo".

Simply create a criteria as normal, and use the User Domain object in the criteria to search for the ID or other properties:

```
Event.createCriteria().list {
     User {
          eqId(1 as Long) //The id of the user you're searching for.
     }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I tried same thing, I am using GGTS and when I put I can see underline for User and eqId saying something wrong with syntax?            public List<Event> getEventsByUser(Long userId){
  try{
   Event.createCriteria().list {
    User {
     eqId(userId) //The id of the user you're searching for.
    }
   }
  }catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: I had it working in IntelliJ - do you get a stack trace or is it just GGTS complaining about the DSL (criteria structure) being incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple use case, you can find all events of particular user as:
    fetch the current user and then

```
def eventList = user?.events
```